# Properly building a function in R

Tags: r, function

I'm writing my first function ever (including any other programming language) and I'm a little confused on the proper structure for `if`, `else` and `ifelse`.  I've searched a ton of examples, but none are that clear to me.

Situation - I'm trying to bucket clients by how long they have been clients for, then turn that into a factor.

```
#Sample Data
clientID <- round(runif(2,min=2000, max=3000),0)
MonthsSinceSignUp <- round(runif(20,min=1, max=60),0)
df <- data.frame(cbind(clientID,MonthsSinceSignUp))
```

For a given client, I would like to determine if they have been so for less than a year, more than year, but less than 2, etc.

This is my first crack at a function:

```
ClientAgeRange <- function(MonthsSinceSignUp) {
  if (MonthsSinceSignUp < 13) {ClientAgeRange <- '1 year'}
} else {
  if (MonthsSinceSignUp > 13 & MonthsSinceSignUps < 25) {ClientAgeRange <- '2 years'}
} else {ClientAgeRage <- '3+ years'}
```

The error that I keep getting is:
`Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`, which would indicate I'm missing or have an extra closing bracket.  However, despite my trouble shooting, I can't locate it.  But - I think in general, I'm not apply the correct structure to the function.  I'm trying to produce a `if this, then set this variable as that`.  How can I structure this function properly?

Lastly - if I wanted to add the output of the function to the `dataframe`, is `apply` the correct way to do so?

Comment: No one seems to have mentioned this minor detail, but all of your clients who signed up 13 months ago will be categorized as '3+ years' unless you change the `> 13` to `>= 13` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer in two parts:

1. A tip
2. A fix

## The tip:

My first tip is to use a code editor that does bracket matching. For example, in `Notepad++` you get this:

*PS. I'm not recommending `Notepad++` - use Rstudio instead - I'm simply using `Notepad++` because of the garish (and thus easy to spot) colours*

[image]

Notice that the highlighted brace (in red) matches with a brace in the middle of your function. This reveals that there is redundant brace at the end of your first `if`.  So, fix that first:

[image]

OK, now there is no matching brace (no highlighted red), so you need to add the missing brace at the end of your function:

[image]

---

## The fix:

But you can vastly simplify your function if you use `cut`, which is designed to do this type of analysis:

```
ClientAgeRange <- function(x) {
  cut(x, breaks=c(0, 13, 25, Inf), labels=c("1 year", "2 years", "3+ years"))
}
```

Try it on your code:

```
ClientAgeRange(df$MonthsSinceSignUp)
 [1] 2 years  1 year   3+ years 2 years  3+ years 3+ years 2 years  2 years  3+ years 3+ years 1 year  
[12] 3+ years 2 years  3+ years 3+ years 3+ years 3+ years 3+ years 3+ years 3+ years
Levels: 1 year 2 years 3+ years
```

Comment: If Andrie's online, it simply doesn't make sense to try typing an answer. I was *just* about to paste a similar `cut` solution (similar because I hadn't wrapped it in a function)... and then I refreshed the page.

Comment: -1 for not using `Curry` (kidding! great answer, especially given that it teaches about function-writing more generally)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (MonthsSinceSignUp < 13) {ClientAgeRange <- '1 year'}
}
```

You have an extra } here.

As a general rule, it's a good idea to adopt conventions for formatting your code.  One convention I would highly recommend is always putting the body of a "block" (here I'm using block as a generic term for "stuff inside {}", which includes function bodies, if statements, and loops) on its own line, as below:

```
ClientAgeRange <- function(MonthsSinceSignUp) {
  if (MonthsSinceSignUp < 13) {
    ClientAgeRange <- '1 year'
  } else if (MonthsSinceSignUp > 13 & MonthsSinceSignUps < 25) {
    ClientAgeRange <- '2 years'
  } else {
    ClientAgeRage <- '3+ years'
  }
}
```

See how that makes everything clearer?

---

As to your second question, a function without side-effects takes input, does stuff, and returns output.  You don't have any return value right now, and from your naming conventions it seems like you are a bit confused.

Try this:

```
ClientAgeRange <- function(MonthsSinceSignUp) {
  if (MonthsSinceSignUp < 13) {
    result <- '1 year'
  } else if (MonthsSinceSignUp > 13 & MonthsSinceSignUps < 25) {
    result <- '2 years'
  } else {
    result <- '3+ years'
  }
  return(result)
}
```

The `return(` is optional in R, but it will help you think through functions more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (note that I used `else if` to make it simpler):

```
ClientAgeRange <- function(MonthsSinceSignUp) {
  if (MonthsSinceSignUp < 13) {
      ClientAgeRange <- '1 year'
  } else if (MonthsSinceSignUp > 13 & MonthsSinceSignUp < 25) {
      ClientAgeRange <- '2 years'
  } else {ClientAgeRage <- '3+ years'}
}
```

Then, you can add it to your dataframe as following:

```
df$ClientAgeRange <- sapply(MonthsSinceSignUp, ClientAgeRange)
```

As you said, apply (I used sapply in this case; there are a couple of places you can go to read about different apply functions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) for example) is the right way to go. This is because we cannot simply pass the entire vector into the function; it requires individual elements to do the necessary comparisons.