# Split vector in quantile in R

Tags: r

```
data <- seq(1:100)
split(data,quantile(data))
```

if I run the above script then I got a list of five subset.
But I want the subset of data having range between 0%-25%,25%-50%,50%-75%,75%-100%.
for example
quantile(data) returns

```
>  0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
> 1.00  25.75  50.50  75.25 100.00
```

so my data will be split in 4 subsets of range

```
 1.00  - 25.75,
 25.75 - 50.50,
 50.50 - 75.25,
 75.25 - 100
```

I can do it manually...but is there any command to make this happen when I will only specify 
the data column and a vector that having the range values like c(1,25.75,50.75,75.25,100)

Comment: Perhaps with `cut` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728419/using-cut-and-quartile-to-generate-breaks-in-r-function

Comment: In other words, try something like `cut(data, quantile(data),  include.lowest = TRUE)`